# Regex to Remove Duplicate URL

Tags: c#, regex, filtering

I have a list which contains set of URL's which is similar to

1. somesite.com/index.php?id=12
2. somesite.com/index.php?id=14
3. somesite.com/index.php?id=156
4. example.com/view.php?image=441
5. somesite.com/page.php?id=1
6. example.com/view.php?ivideo=4
7. somesite.com/page.php?id=56
8. example.com/view.php?image=1

These are stored into a list and then display on a listview after a crawling process.
i tried different regex patters but still couldn't archive what i exactly need because query string became a problem.

Here is one of the patterns i tried.

```
(http://?)(w*)(\.*)(\w*)(\.)(\w*)
```

let me write how i need the above URL's to be filtered.

1. somesite.com/index.php?id=12
2. example.com/view.php?image=441
3. somesite.com/page.php?id=1
4. example.com/view.php?ivideo=4

Well as you can see , the pages which are the same but with different query strings have been removed. This is what i want to archive. Please do note that the above links does contain **http://** but did not include them since the SOF finds them as spam. Can anyone be kind to help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and why would `example.com/view.php?image=1` match..according to your example it matches `example.com/view.php?image=441`

Comment: What criteria are you trying to filter them with? What distinguishing factor is indicated that your trying to filter?

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ
Sry , i made a mistake their. now its corrected.

Comment: Is it only the first one you want? What is it that you want. Looks like you want only the first non consecutive url of each site . correct ?

Comment: See [8 Regular Expressions You Should Know](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/): "Matching a URL"

Comment: @Slartibartfast
I dont know what non consecutive means but i don't want the same page with different query strings to appear on the list.

I hope you got it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parsing the Url's manually, you can make use of the [**`Uri`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class and [**`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) to do the parsing.  Here's an example using the LINQ [**`.GroupBy`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method to collect similar urls into groups, then select the first url from the group.

```
var distinctUrls = urls.GroupBy (u =>
    {
        var uri = new Uri(u);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
        var baseUri = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + uri.AbsolutePath;
        return new {
            Uri = baseUri,
            QueryStringKeys = string.Join("&", query.AllKeys.OrderBy (ak => ak))
        };
    })
    .Select (g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Sample Output of `distinctUrls`:

```
http://somesite.com/index.php?id=12
http://example.com/view.php?image=441
http://somesite.com/page.php?id=1
http://example.com/view.php?ivideo=4
```

This will also correctly handle the case where two urls have an identical set of querystring parameters, but in a different order, such as `example.com/view.php?image=441&order=asc` and `example.com/view.php?order=desc&image=441` - treating them as similar.

Comment: Thank you for the kind , i have my set of URLS saved to the list "results". Could you help me to implement this solution?

Comment: You will need to include library `System.Web.dll` in your application.  Also, you will need imports for `System.Linq` and `System.Web` at the top of your code file.  Then the code above can be put in a method, or you can just replace `urls.GroupBy` with your variable name, i.e., `results.GroupBy`, and it should give you the desired output list into `distinctUrls` that you can work with.

Comment: Thank you but still this line of code
` string.Join("&", query.AllKeys.OrderBy(ak => ak))` Produces a error

**The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments**

and also the compilwr mentions that
**Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'**

Anyway to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, it worked when I tested it.  You can try `query.AllKeys.OrderBy (ak => ak).ToArray()` instead, so that it is passing in an array.